# Convergence in probability and inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am currently trying to work on a problem in Basic Probability Theory by Robert B Ash (see [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf)). I am working on question 1 in section 5.4 (page 176) which is showing that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution. I am slightly stuck on the answer to question 1 given on page 310. Note that in what follows $R,R_n$ are random variables.
So I need to show that
$$P(R_n\le x, R\gt x+\epsilon)\le P(|R_n-R|\ge \epsilon)$$
Now Ash states that this is due to the fact that $R_n\le x, R\gt x+\epsilon$ implies $|R_n-R|\ge \epsilon.$ This is the bit I am stuck on. I am not sure how to show this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R_n\le x$ so $-R_n\ge-x$. Moreover $R>x+\varepsilon$ so by summation $R-R_n>x+\varepsilon-x=\varepsilon$.

Since $\varepsilon>0$ this also proves that $R-R_n>0$ so $\vert R_n-R\vert=R-R_n>\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your response. Okay, but how do I get $\ge \epsilon$? Is it simply that if $|R_n-R| \gt \epsilon$ then $|R_n-R|$ also satisfies $|R_n-R| \ge \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but shouldn't $R>x+\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes it is $R>x+\varepsilon$, I edited it. And yes the strict inequality implies the large inequality.